# How can I move the object down slowly?

Tags: unity, c#

In the first script I'm doing some manipulations on the object one of them is rotation:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectsManipulation : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Camera
    public Camera playerCamera;

    //Scaling
    private Scaling scaling;

    //Lights
    public DimLights dimlights;
    private Coroutine lightCoroutine;

    //Colors
    private Colors colors;

    //Rotating
    public bool stopRotation = false;
    private Rotating rotating;

    private void Start()
    {
        scaling = GetComponent<Scaling>();
        scaling.Inits();

        colors = GetComponent<Colors>();
        colors.Start();

        rotating = GetComponent<Rotating>();
    }

    // Use this for initialization
    void Update()
    {
        //Scaling
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            //Flip the scale direction when F key is pressed
            scaling.scaleUp = !scaling.scaleUp;

            //Stop old coroutine
            if (scaling.scaleCoroutine != null)
                StopCoroutine(scaling.scaleCoroutine);

            if (lightCoroutine != null)
                StopCoroutine(lightCoroutine);


            //Scale  up
            if (scaling.scaleUp)
            {
                //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
                rotating.rotateBack = false;
                scaling.scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaling.scaleOverTime(scaling.objectToScale, scaling.maxSize, scaling.duration));
                lightCoroutine = StartCoroutine(dimlights.dimLightOverTime(1, scaling.duration));
            }

            //Scale Down
            else
            {
                //Start new coroutine and scale up within 5 seconds and return the coroutine reference
                rotating.rotateBack = true;
                scaling.scaleCoroutine = StartCoroutine(scaling.scaleOverTime(scaling.objectToScale, scaling.minSize, scaling.duration));
                lightCoroutine = StartCoroutine(dimlights.dimLightOverTime(0, scaling.duration)); ;
            }
        }

        //Rotate
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.R) && !scaling.scaleUp)
        {
            rotating.x += Time.deltaTime * rotating.rotationSpeed;
            scaling.objectToScale.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotating.x);
            rotating.keyPressed = true;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.R))
        {
            rotating.keyPressed = false;
        }

        if (!rotating.keyPressed && !scaling.scaleUp && rotating.rotateBack == false
            && DetectInteractable.detected == false)
        {
            scaling.objectToScale.transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(playerCamera.transform.forward);
        }

        if (DetectInteractable.detected == true && !scaling.scaleUp && stopRotation == false)
        {
            rotating.x += Time.deltaTime * rotating.rotationSpeed;
            scaling.objectToScale.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotating.x);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the rotation part:

```
if (DetectInteractable.detected == true && !scaling.scaleUp && stopRotation == false)
            {
                rotating.x += Time.deltaTime * rotating.rotationSpeed;
                scaling.objectToScale.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, 0, rotating.x);
            }
```

In another script I did that if the player will click on the mouse left button the rotation will stop:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NaviCamera : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Navi;
    public ObjectsManipulation om;

    private void Start()
    {

    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            om.stopRotation = true;
            Navi.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);
        }
    }
}
```

Stopping the rotation is working but moving Navi down is not.
It's just does nothing. The Navi just stop rotating and hang.

What I want to do is to make the Navi to move down smooth slowly and stop on the ground. Not falling or bouncing just direct smooth slowly down.

[image: Navi]

The NAVI is child of MainCamers that is child of Player.
And the script NaviCamera is attached to the NaviCamera that is a child of NAVI.

And I don't want to move Player or MainCamnera only to move NAVI directly down slowly smooth and stop on ground.

UPDATE

I tried this:

```
private void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            om.stopRotation = true;
        }

        if (om.stopRotation == true)
            Navi.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

It's getting to:

```
Navi.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime);
```

But the object is not moving.
Maybe since the NAVI is child of the Player it won't move ?

Comment: Do you have any other scripts that touch this object's position, like a follow script?

Comment: I found that if I attached the script to the NAVI it self and use transform it's working.  Instead  transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime, Space.World); then  Navi.transform.Translate(Vector3.down * Time.deltaTime, Space.World);

Comment: Sounds like your Navi variable might not be pointing where you think it is. Or you have an order of execution bug, where something runs after the player script and overrides the movement it applied to Navi, but running it on Navi itself happens later and so it doesn't get stomped over.